# Liquibase fails during checking of non-existence of primary key

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector, liquibase, mariadb

During the replacement of mysql-connector to MariaDB I came to the situation when Liquibase fails on the changeset where I check non-existence of primary key:

```
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <primaryKeyExists tableName="users"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
```

It fails with NullPointerException

```
Error: null java.lang.NullPointerException at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.MySQLDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.convertPrimaryKeyName(MySQLDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:124)
at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.readPrimaryKeys(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:759)
at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.createSnapshot(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:243)
at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(DatabaseSnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:69)
at liquibase.precondition.core.PrimaryKeyExistsPrecondition.check(PrimaryKeyExistsPrecondition.java:52)
at liquibase.precondition.core.NotPrecondition.check(NotPrecondition.java:30)
at liquibase.precondition.core.AndPrecondition.check(AndPrecondition.java:34)
at liquibase.precondition.core.PreconditionContainer.check(PreconditionContainer.java:199)
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:249)
```

If I remove this clause the liquibase works fine. Interesting thing is that other preConditions work fine, for example, which check some table existence.

After diving in the code I found that the issue is in JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator#readPrimaryKeys, where we try to fetch primary keys. But of course, for different databases there are different implementations, so it seems that it is a bit different ResultSet (with null column for primary key) which I get using MariaDB, however, the funny thing is that the method (in MySQLDatabaseSnapshotGenerator) where it fails is like this:

```
@Override
protected String convertPrimaryKeyName(String pkName) throws SQLException {
    if (pkName.equals("PRIMARY")) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return pkName;
    }
}
```

So, just if it is opposite way around it would work for me:) Like this I mean:

```
if ("PRIMARY".equals(pkName))
```

THE QUESTION: Is it a bug of liquibase or maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I hate that about Java.

Comment: Yes, that's not a good thing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research I came to this conclusion.

Probably it is a bug of liquibase, but as I found we are using quite old version 2.0.5.
Upgrade to current 3.2.0 didn't help at all because even the first changeset fails and it doesn't matter which driver I am using (mysql-connector or mariadb) and which database (MySQL or PostgreSQL). Plus one of the main things what I found was that liquibase actually doesn't have a support for MariaDb according to this ticket: 
https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1411

Moreover, I was thinking that maybe MariaDb has some other version, but seems there is only one by now:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jumpmind.symmetric.jdbc/mariadb-java-client

So, in general removing of these preConditions fixes my problem, the databases are the same at least with the clean installation. However, i am still thinking that it shouldn't be like this, so would be nice to hear some other thoughts if someone has.

Comment: The code you were having problems with doesn't exist in 3.2.0. I've done a little testing with mariadb on 3.2.1 and it seems to generally work for me. If you are having specific problems, can you add them to the CORE-1411 issue so they can be investigated?

Comment: I will definitely do so when come back to this problem. There are some other parts in our application which can influence on the queries which I haven't investigated yet.